# which mysql datatype generate which form field in cake bake

Tags: mysql, cakephp

when cake bake all issued in version 2.7 it generates arbitrary form fields or is there any specific rules that this MySQL datatype generate this type form field. can any body give a small list mapping MySQL datatype generates text form field ...

Answer (score 0):

The rules for automatic fields in forms are defined by the `magicOptions` function in the `FormHelper`

You can give it a read here:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1200-L1264

The important thing to notice is that it uses a combination of the field name and the mysql type. The rules for types are defined by this array inside the function:

```
$map = array(
            'string' => 'text', 'datetime' => 'datetime',
            'boolean' => 'checkbox', 'timestamp' => 'datetime',
            'text' => 'textarea', 'time' => 'time',
            'date' => 'date', 'float' => 'number',
            'integer' => 'number', 'decimal' => 'number',
            'binary' => 'file'
        );
```